# Can't disable windows defender real-time protection

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I'm trying to disable real-time protection, but it says it is managed by my administrator, but it's my own computer and i'm the administrator, what can I do?

I am using Windows 10 Home, so I don't have the group policy editor.

[image]

Comment: What 3rd party AntiVirus  are you using?  Try the following settings from Group Policy Editor to turn WD real time OFF:  Group Policy Editor:
Computer configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Defender
Turn off Windows Defender  (set to Enabled)

Computer configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Defender
 -> Real-time protection
Turn off Real Time Protection (set to Enabled)

OK and exit out . Default setting is Not Configured

Comment: @John I have Windows 10 home edition so I don't have access to group policy editor

Comment: From an admin command prompt run `sc stop WinDefend`

Comment: 99% of the time when "This setting is managed by your Administrator" is display it's due to a require setting being disabled.  The message that displays when it's disabled by a group policy is slightly different